# A way to check for specific month in specific year sql?

Tags: sql

Out of curiosity I was playing around with SQL, and as we all know, `DATEPART()` and `DATENAME()` can be used to check for tuples with a specific day, year, or month as a condition for us to browse through records in a relation.

But I was just curious whether there is a way to check for both at the same time without using something like:

```
DATENAME(MONTH,Datevariable1)="February" AND
DATEPART(DAY,Datevariable2)="26"`
```

to find these records.

Is there a simpler way of doing it? I am asking this question just out of curiosity.

Comment: *What* SQL? Do you mean MS SQL Server? Please [edit] your post to tag it.

Comment: `DATENAME()` and `DATEPART()` are not standard SQL functions. You need to tell us which specific DBMS product you are using. In "SQL" (the standard query language) it would be `extract(month from some_date) = 2`

Answer (score 0):

The month() function will call back a specific month. the range is 0 not a month and 1-12 in this case you wanted Feb so we check month against 2.  And the day function acts the same way it will look for that day which is set to 26 in this case. Hope it Helps.

The mysql Statement

```
SELECT *, MONTH(dateColumn)=2 and DAY(dateColumn)=26 as 'MY_MONTH_AND_DAY' FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

By that you want a function that can return "26 Feb" instead of 26 alone and Feb alone?

If that the case you can use something like this in SQL Server

```
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), dateColumn, 6),6)
```